Multiple Set-Cookie header in Apache camel exchange
I am trying to add 2 cookies for access and refresh tokens.
Adding headers like :
exchange.getIn().setHeader(Http headers.SET_COOKIE, cookie1)
exchange.getIn().setHeader(Http headers.SET_COOKIE, cookie2)

This is not working as headers is a map and multiple key will just override previous one.
Tried searching for add/append headers availability in exchange header object but looks like  I can only set headers.
